# getting the value in dropdown and use it as table name when inserting

Tags: php, mysql

What is wrong with this? any help will be appreciated. its not inserting. I need to specify which table will be inserted to depend on the value of the dropdown thats why i put insert into $newCandidatePosition. It's working when i put insert into president. But when i put insert into $newcandidateposition it's not working. What should i do?

This is my dropdown list

```
<select name="position" id="position">select
    <OPTION value="select">select
    <option value="president">PRESIDENT</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

and this is the submit

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    $id = $_POST['name']; 
    $newCandidatePosition = $_POST['position']; 
    $query=mysql_query("select * from voting_tbCandidates where student_id='".$id."'")or die(mysql_error());
    $duplicate=mysql_num_rows($query);

    if($duplicate==0){
        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO '$newCandidatePosition'(`stud_id_no`,`stud_name`, `lname`,`stud_grade`,`stud_img`,`stud_section`)"." SELECT `stud_id_no`,`stud_name`, `lname`,`stud_grade`,`stud_img`,`stud_section`"." FROM sid_senior_high_table WHERE id_no='$id'");
    }else{

    }
}
```

Comment: you need to tell wat is wrong ? What is not working ?

Comment: Try inspecting the network tab and see what payload is sent to server.

Comment: it's not adding. I think there is something wrong when i declare the table name with $newcandidateposition

Comment: but when i put the table name with  INSERT INTO president. it's working. But i need to specify which table will be inserted depend on the drop down value. That's why i put insert into $newcandidateposition

Comment: @KosakiOnodera  show your complete form code.

Comment: Your comments in the code are funny. You want to prevent sql injection and you use mysql_*

Comment: there are syntax errors i hope. Turn on your error and check if you have any  displayed.

Comment: where is the bluddy form to post selected values? also don't use `deprecated+removed mysql_*` version. Go to `mysqli_*` OR `PDO` along with `prepared statements` to prevent from `SQL INJECTION`

Comment: @Akintunde maybe instead of saying what he is doing wrong, you should tell him what to do instead. To prevent SQL injection, you should use [Prepared Statements](https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)

Comment: You need to check if you get the desired values in the `$_POST`. try printing the values and check if they are fetched correctly.

Comment: @KosakiOnodera  :  first thing do not use table name as "select" .. second thing   '$newCandidatePosition' change  $newCandidatePosition remove single code

Comment: @KosakiOnodera : solution is worked or not.

Answer (score 0):

Please close option tag properly

```
<select name="position" id="position">
<option value="select">select</option>
<option value="president">PRESIDENT</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
```

first thing do not use table name as "select" .. second thing '$newCandidatePosition' change $newCandidatePosition remove single code

```
    //echo "INSERT INTO $newCandidatePosition (`stud_id_no`)"." SELECT `stud_id_no`"." FROM test2 WHERE id_no='$id'";
 $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $newCandidatePosition (`stud_id_no`)"." SELECT `stud_id_no`"." FROM test2 WHERE id_no='$id'");
echo mysql_insert_id();
```

above is my demo code it's work for me

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way:

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO 
              '" .$newCandidatePosition. "'
              (`stud_id_no`,`stud_name`, `lname`,`stud_grade`,`stud_img`,`stud_section`)".
          " SELECT `stud_id_no`,`stud_name`, `lname`,`stud_grade`,`stud_img`,`stud_section`".
            " FROM sid_senior_high_table WHERE id_no='$id'")";
```

Comment: i think its because, the above code has many issues like what is `stud_id_no`, `stud_name ` ? What does it refer to ?

Comment: @Panther I'm assuming those are the fields that exist in all the tables given in dropdown list.

Comment: Also never give answers using old deprecated api like mysql_* .not my down vote though

Comment: @Akintunde I found a small syntax problem in OP's code and I changed it because that's what being asked in question. Once, it works properly, then it's fine to suggest other APIs. I mean that's just my mindset.